# Error using WCF service

Tags: web-services, wcf

This are my first steps in programming ap WCF service using a tutorial from the MSDN sites.

What i've done:

1. creating a service project (ASP.NET Web Application in VS 2013)
2. creating an Entity Data Model (EF 6) from existing MS sample database (AdventureWorksLT) including a database table
3. creating the service ("Add New Item", Template "WCF Data Service" Name "AdventureWorksService")
4. configuring the service by copy and paste the source code for the service from the MSDN site
5. creating the WPF Client Application by adding a new WPF application template to the solution
6. add a new data source from type "Service"
7. in the dialog box "Add Service Reference" i clicked on "Discover"
   The created service "AdventureWorksService" appears in the list of available services with the address "http://localhost:53948/AdventureWorksService.svc".

Now i have to click the button "OK" to download the service information. At this point, i receive an error (beware, that I', using a German Visual Studio, so the translation may not match the original message in English Version:

"Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from the address. Make sure, the address is correct"

If i click the linklabel "Details", i get the following informations:

```html
**Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from "http://localhost:53948/AdventureWorksService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata".**

--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  ...
</html>
--.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: "http://localhost:53948/AdventureWorksService.svc".
The contenttype "text/html" of the message doesn't match with the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8).
```

There's no App.config in the service project, but a Web.Config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Weitere Informationen zum Konfigurieren der ASP.NET-Anwendung finden Sie unter
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksLTEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AdventureWorksModel.csdl|res://*/AdventureWorksModel.ssdl|res://*/AdventureWorksModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MB-SQL2008;initial catalog=AdventureWorksLT;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I guess it has to do with the HTTP-protocol, which is not defined in the service.

Can you help me what to do? I hope, i've posted all the neccessary information.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Can you show me your web.config , it seems like metadata are not enabled

Comment: I added it in the original post now. Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer that may solve your problem , if it doesn't work , put the tutorial link so I can see the code and find out what s missing

Comment: Unfortunately adding your metadata wouldn't solve it. Here is the link [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465161.aspx). What i've forgot to say: when creating the service and chosing the ASP.NET Web Application project template, i select "Empty", not "WebForms", "MVC" ...

Comment: @MichaelBayer I've same problem. how do you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add metadata like this within system.servicemodel tag

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors></behaviors>
```